# Using multiple DropDownLists to filter each other and then GridView items - ASP.net VB

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview, ado.net

I have an ASP.net web page with VB code behind linking to an MS SQL DB.  On the web page I have 4 DropDownLists and 1 GridView.  Each DDL is populated with a SELECT DISTINCT query on 4 corresponding columns from 1 table in the DB.

What I would like to be able to do is: when any of the DDLs have their selected item changed the other DDLs are updated.  Crude example:

DDL1 has a list of first names and DDL2 has a list of last names.  When someone selects a name from DDL1, DDL2 gets updated to only show last names belonging to people with corresponding first names and vice versa.

When the user has chosen their filter criteria they could then hit a 'submit' button and display a list of results in the GridView.

The idea being that someone can filter by 1 DDL or by all DLLs or any combination in between.

I am a bit of a novice and early attempts using IF statements failed as the amount of 'logic' needed rises exponentially with each DDL.

I have searched around and only found semi-relevant materials that do not do exactly as I need and often in differing languages which I feel is odd as this seems such a handy thing to be able to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the link below for multiple `DropDownList`s in `GridView`:

http://dotnetsridhar.blogspot.in/2012/04/multiple-dropdownlists-in-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use if else statement for this or you could use Cascading dropdown using ajax
here are some samples and tutorial http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx

Using If else statement you could do it via binding, ** try to use sql command WHERE ** 
and bind it to DDL2

Comment: The problem with using if else would be that I would need a LOT of them to cover every possible combination of DDL selections.  My crude example above only had 2 DLLs and it is easy to control what they display by putting the if statements on the onselectedchange event of each DDL.  But when you add more DDLs the number and complexity of the if statements grows massively.